# Blue moving bar in VSCode under the Tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know what the blue moving line (from left to right) under the tabs in Visual Studio Code means?
This is no the same that appears in the explorer.
I observed at:

```
Version: 1.58.2
Commit: c3f126316369cd610563c75b1b1725e0679adfb3
Date: 2021-07-14T22:09:06.581Z
Electron: 12.0.13
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.5.0
```

Comment: This likely depends on what extensions you have.  Can you post a list of those as well as a picture of this bar?

Comment: it is some kind of progress bar or busy bar

Comment: RIO is correct, it is a progress bar. There are a few different places progress bars can popup, that is one of them. I find it pops up when my console bugs out, and is unable to finish a process, or if I have a large amount of data loaded and I execute the search widget &/or extension to navigate through it.